# Remove character and special symbol and Convert String to array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a string like "D-30-25-4", then I want 30 and 25 as the 
 desired result

I have tried this

```
value = "D-30-25-4";
value1= parseInt(value.substring(5,7)); // 25
value12 = parseInt(value.substring(2,4)); //30
```

but it fails when value is "D-30-100-4";

Comment: `"D-30-25-4".split('-')[1]` and `"D-30-25-4".split('-')[2]` should give you the result

Comment: `var parts = value.split("-"); console.log(+parts[1],+parts[2]);`

Answer (score 3):

split function of String is your friend.

```
value = "D-30-25-4";
var vals = value.split("-");
value1= vals[2]; // 25
value12 = vals[1]; //30
```

Comment: @Dinesh Next time, If you find any typo's, please feel free to  edit the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could split and slice the string for item at index `1` and `2`.

```js
function parts(s) {
    return s.split('-').slice(1, 3);
}

var object = { 2: "D-30-25-4", 3: "D-30-50-4", 4: "D-30-10-4", 15: "D-30-100-4" };
    
console.log(parts(object[2]));
console.log(parts(object[15]));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
let [,value1,value12] = value.split('-').map(parseFloat)
```

Comment: That's crazy elegant. Hats off.

Answer (score 1):

Use split operation. split returns array

```js
var res = {"2":"D-30-25-4",
"3":"D-30-50-4",
"4":"D-30-10-4",
"15":"D-30-100-4"};


for(obj in res){
  var result = res[obj].split("-");
  // result will have ["D","30","25",4"];

  console.log(result[1]);
  console.log(result[2]);
  console.log(result[3]);

}
```

Comment: Instead of splitting the string on each line, you should do it once, store it, and reuse the variable.